# how can i initialize textBox values in a popup window in TelerikRadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using TelerikRadGrid in C# ASP.NET. When I press Edit it opens a separate popup window using

`<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID" EditMode="PopUp" CommandItemDisplay="Bottom" GridLines="None" Width="100"`>

but how can I initialize the TextBox in this popup because in editing not all TextBoxes are empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the second grid example here: [Grid / PopUp Edit Form](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/popupeditform/defaultcs.aspx)